# What was the "sae-urn" protocol on port 4500?

Tags: ip, port

Port 4500 is a documented home to [a couple of standards:](https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=4500)

- `4500` - `ipsec-nat-t` - IPSec NAT Traversal
- `4500` - `sae-urn`

IP-Sec NAT traversal is explained in a number of RFCs:

- rfc3947 - [Negotiation of NAT-Traversal in the IKE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3947)
- rfc3948 - [UDP Encapsulation of IPsec ESP Packets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3948)
- rfc7296 - [Internet Key Exchange Protocol Version 2 (IKEv2)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7296)
- rfc8229 - [TCP Encapsulation of IKE and IPsec Packets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8229)

### But what was **sae-urn**?

It seems to have passed out of all knowledge.

The oldest reference i can find to *"sae-urn"* comes from the port service mapping of nmap [from May 21, 1997:](http://b2chem.eu/services.html)

```
sae-urn         4500/tcp            # sae-urn
sae-urn         4500/udp            # sae-urn
```

Someone tried asking [what *sae-urn* is](https://comp.unix.bsd.freebsd.misc.narkive.com/q3yxv16f/what-is-sae-urn-udp-port-4500) on a BSD newsgroup in 2002  - but in typical Stackoverflow fashion, people condescendently didn't answer the question:

> Googling on that gives this reference.
> The rest is an exercise for the reader.

Whatever the `sae-urn` was, it seems to have been lost to the sands of time.

Does anyone remember what it was?

Comment: Do note that the initial nmap service list was assembled by nobody else but the nmap author based on their observations, and some of its original entries might outright have made-up names. (It used to have an entry "distrib-netassholes 2064/tcp # A group of lamers"...)

Comment: *"A group of lamers working on a silly closed-source client for solving the RSA cryptographic challenge.  This is the keyblock proxy port."*

Comment: Yes. Based on such and similar entries (e.g. the one for port 31337), my own opinion would be that it's an inaccurate entry that everyone else just copied _from_ nmap's database. But what do I know. I'm only here to answer in typical Stackoverflow fashion.